# ethtool on Ubuntu and an USB to Ethernet adapter

Tags: 12.04, usb, ethernet

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, recently I purchased an USB to Ethernet adapter.

The dmesg command shows the model as "Davicom DM9601 USB Ethernet". I'm unable to use ethtool to modify any of its settings.

```
jesin@localhost:~$ sudo ethtool eth1
Settings for eth1:
    Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                         100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
    Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 100Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: MII
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                   drv probe link
    Link detected: yes
```

When I try to change the speed of the adapter to 10Mbps I get

```
jesin@localhost:~$ sudo ethtool -s eth1 speed 10
Cannot advertise speed 10
```

I cannot even change the port type

```
jesin@localhost:~$ sudo ethtool -s eth1 port tp
Cannot set new settings: Invalid argument
  not setting port
```

What is causing this problem ?

Additional info:

```
jesin@localhost:~$ sudo ethtool --version
ethtool version 3.1
jesin@localhost:~$ uname -r
3.2.0-39-generic
```

Comment: bro, be sure to contact your provider to get info about your connection, some providers has their own settings that disallow you to edit something, sometimes they can be blocked some ports 22 for example and you can not allow it beacause it is blocked there and so on... so be sure to ask them for your connection specifications, that can solve many of your problems when you know what are you dealing with.

Comment: Dimitris do you mean the chipset manufacturers have blocked the ability to change the speed and duplex of the adapter ?